# Login Required on Google Cloud Storage client in PHP

Tags: php, google-api, google-cloud-storage, google-api-php-client

I'm getting frustrated and confused from the documentation.

I have a server code that needs to upload images to Google Cloud Storage. Nothing fancy, everything is done with my own user directly from my server code to GCS, no fuss, no "classic" user authentication.

Tried doing it with authenticate, and API key, both giving me 401 Login required.

What am I doing wrong?
Code:

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("upload photo");
$client->setDeveloperKey("<my API key>"); 
$client->setClientId("XXXXXXXXX@developer.gserviceaccount.com");
$client->setClientSecret("<my secret>");
$client->setRedirectUri("http://<my public IP address>"); #this server is on GCE
$service = new Google_Service_Storage($client);

$data = $service->buckets->get("<bucket name>");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An API key isn't part of authentication and grants no privileges. It is merely a marker, mostly useful for anonymous calls, that says "this request is related to this project." It's useful for quota and tracking and such.

Do you need to authenticate as an account with permission to manipulate your project, or as an end user? Assuming the first one (called a service account), you'll need a service account (which was probably already created for you) and a private key for that account, which will live with your deployed code. There's an example and instruction here: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/guide/aaa_oauth2_service

Comment: can't seem to find anywhere the private key... I did download the secrets json from the console but if I try to use it as $key I get: Unable to parse the p12 file.  Is this a .p12 file?  Is the password correct?  OpenSSL error: ' in /var/www/cookila/html/application/google/src/Google/Signer/P12.php:52
 I will highly appreciate if you can direct me to the right place...

Comment: There are instructions here: https://developers.google.com/drive/web/service-accounts 

You'll want to click "Create New Client ID", follow the prompts, and you should be given a p12 file.